# How to connect 3rd part external apps to private RDS though ProxySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, proxysql

I have private RDS which I want 3rd party applications to be able to access,without making it public, I created EC2 in public subnet and installed ProxySQL, configured ProxySQL to be able to access RDS DB.

When I am trying to access RDS DB from EC2 public IP, I am having errors:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'PUBLIC IP:6033' (111)
```

Question: How to connect 3rd party applications thru ProxySQL?